# Remmina RDP - No sound from remote Windows 7 computer - Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: sound, 13.10, windows-7, remmina

I'm connecting to a Windows 7 computer from Ubuntu 13.10.  I have the Sound setting in the Advanced tab of the Remote Desktop Preferences for my connection set to "Local - low quality".

In my remote desktop session, if I go to the Sound controls under the Playback tab, I see that "No audio devices are installed".

Does anyone know of a way to get the audio from my remote Windows 7 computer to my Ubuntu 13.10 computer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same problem, couldn't fix it, i installed 2XRDP and after that the problem was solved, probably a setting are lib-file was update

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I haven't found any alternative solutions either.  I guess this can just be chalked up to an issue with Remmina RDP.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem using Ubuntu 14.04. Tried with Remmina, 2XRDP and rdesktop - no audio with any of them. Looked around and found reference to the "esound" package on the 2X site.

Installed it using `sudo apt-get install esound` and in response got the message:

> Note, selecting 'pulseaudio-esound-compat' instead of 'esound'

... but it installed and worked with Remmina with no further fuss (make sure sound is turned on in the "Advanced" tab).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have this set up anymore so I'm afraid I can't try out your solution. Thanks for the response! Hopefully it helps someone else out.

Comment: Didn't work for me (Ubuntu 14.04, Remmina, connecting to Windows 10)

Comment: I'm on 12.04 (don't ask) and this worked for me after rebooting. Probably just the pulseaudio service needed restarting after the new package was installed.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install esound` worked for me! No sound before, good sound after. RDP remote connect from Remmina 1.1.2 on Ubuntu16.04 to Windows 10 on Azure. Chose 'local - medium quality' on advaced tab when editing connection.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by setting "Edit/Advanced/Audio output mode" to "local".
I had a same problem, but after setting this, I could hear sound from remote computer.
Hope this works for you as well.